# Error ET Geowizard Clean Polygon() takes no arguments (3 given)

Tags: polygon, python-2.7, python-script-tool, et-geowizards

I want to clean polygon feature classes with ET Geowizards (clean polygon) because I cannot find any tool within ArcMap (ArcInfo) that does the same. [I have really small gaps within the polygons (but no overlaps), which should be removed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWunL.jpg)
The process is running well (the most time) in ArcMap. I am using a large python script with different steps and it has worked as well the first time but since a few days the script fails at the ET Tool with the CMD message "ET Geowizard Clean Polygon() takes no arguments (3 given)". The tool does not start the process, it fails at the beginning.

I did not change the input data, code or software! The ET logfile does not contain any information, only "Error". I am using the same data input for testing the whole time, is has just a few MB. I tried the tool via CMD on different machines, in ArcMap 10.1 and ArcMap 10.2. Always the same.

- I have installed the last update of ET Geowizards (11.2 for ArcGIS 10.2, 14 Dec 2014)
- Python version 2.7.5 64 bit (not running with 32 bit because of memory (2 GB memory is NOT reached during the ET process)
- ArcMap 10.2.2

The data input is a feature class within a FGDB, output the same, Fuzzy tolerance 0.5 meters. The code was running well... but now?

```
(myWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) (FGDB), LN_STREETS_DISSOLVE is an output feature class that is created before)

try:
    CleanPolygonResult = myWorkspace + os.sep + "final_streets"

    arcpy.AddMessage("Clean Polygons")
    arcpy.ET_GPCleanPolygon(LN_STREETS_DISSOLVE, CleanPolygonResult, "0.5")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Clean Polygons done")

except Exception as ex:
# If an error occurred
    arcpy.AddError("Clean Polygons failed: " + str(ex))
    sys.exit()
```

Any ideas why the Tool fails? I would also be glad if I could solve the problem without the ET Geowizards, only using ArcMap tools but it has to run within the python script, not by manual editing :) Nevertheless I am interested in the problem of the ET Tool...

Comment: Well, ET Geowizards don´t support 64 bit. Nice that there seems to be no information on the website and that there is no clear error message... So I have to check out where the memory is increasing...

Comment: What ArcGIS license level do you have? If you have an Advanced license, look at the Conflation toolset.

Comment: All licences are available until ArcInfo. The Conflation toolset is only for polyline feature but I am using polygons in this case. Currently I removed the ET Tool in the script. Its the last step that could be done manually. Now I can run the script with python 64 bit and have no memory problems. Nevertheless thanks for your answer! :)